# The connection is already in a transaction and cannot participate in another transaction

Tags: ef-core-2.1

I am calling this method:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteObject<T>(string query, Func<DbDataReader, T> map)
    {

        var  trx = miContexto.Database.BeginTransaction();
        var entities = new List<T>();

        miContexto.Database.OpenConnection();

        using (var command = miContexto.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Transaction = trx.GetDbTransaction();

            using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (result.Read())
                {
                    entities.Add(map(result));
                }
            }
        }

        trx.Commit();
        trx.Dispose();
        return entities;
    }
```

From MVC controller by this lines:

```
        var result = c.ExecuteObject(
                "SELECT TOP 10 Nombre, Apellido FROM Persona "
                + " GROUP BY Nombre, Apellido ORDER BY Apellido DESC",
                x => new Persona {
                    Nombre = (string)x[0],
                    Apellido = (string)x[1], });

        result.ToList();


        return View();
```

It works most of the time but every often it throws the exception "The connection is already in a transaction and cannot participate in another transaction".

Any ideas. I tried to solve it in many different ways but unsuccessfully.
I used using(transaction scope), using(dbcontext.database.opentransaction). but this exceptions appears with all this options.

Comment: Have you managed to solve it?